# MVC 3 Model passing to the defined section

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have "LoginBox" section defined in _Layout.cshtml, and its model is AccountModel. So it'll always display in every page, but i want to know that, do i really have to pass that model in every ViewModel? My example IndexViewModel is like this:

```
public class IndexViewModel
    {
        public BulletinModel Bulletin { get; set; }
        public CategoryModel Category { get; set; }
    }
```

I can add this model to this viewmodel but do i really have to do that in every viewmodel? Can i define it like a global model, i don't know if it makes any performance problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to pass your additional Model to each of your main ViewModel, you may also want to try with @Html.RenderAction(ActionName, ControllerName)

- Create a new Action Method and create a Partial View for that new Action.
- Put (or) create your Model(additional) in your new Action Method and pass it to your Partial View.
- Call this new Action method from your _Layout page with Html.RenderAction().

> @{ Html.RenderAction("ActionName", "ControllerName"); }

Answer (score 1):

No, you absolutely don't have to define it in every ViewModel.  Typically, in the _Layout View you will have persisting elements of the layout defined as such:

```
@using YourModelsNS

@* layout markup omitted for brevity *@

<div id="header">
        <div id="title">
            <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="logindisplay">
            @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial", new YourMode() { SomeString = "Test" })
        </div>
        <div id="menucontainer">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Test", "Test")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice here that in the View you see `@Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")`.  This is what then renders the particular View, _LogOnPartial.cshtml.  Which contains this markup:

```
@model YourModelNS.YourModel

@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!
    [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
}
else {
    @:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}

@Model.SomeString
```

This is separate from the content pages that are rendered through @RenderBody(), therefore you won't be needing to include separate concerns within all ViewModels or Views themselves.

**EDIT**: Code has been edited to pass a model object to the Partial View.  Now every content page (by `RenderBody()` is ignorant to the `YourModel` Model, and their corresponding ViewModels don't have to know anything about it.

*Disclaimer: I do not recommend the above code practice, the omission of Controller logic is simply to focus on the question at hand.*

Comment: But i use a section, because it opens a modal popup window and that window has a form post to logon. So i have to use a model to pass it to that section. Does it matter to use a section over a partial view?

Comment: Sorry now i see that, in that section i use Partial View, stupid question... But i don't understand how do i pass that model on every page?

Comment: @mehmetserif See my edit.  Let me know if that gives you a better idea.  Focus primarily on the altered `@Html.Partial()` call in the _Layout.cshtml View, as well as referencing the model in the partial view itself.